# Wordpress to Telegram Auto Posting Code Sharing Draft

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I created a code which can send WordPress posts to a Telegram channel when I publish a new post or update an existing one. The code is working fine as it shares the post to Telegram when I update or publish the post. However, the problem is that when I save a draft on WordPress, it also triggers the share function and shares the draft URL, which is the preview URL of the post. Here is the code, and I hope anyone can help me with this.

```
function send_telegram_message($message) {
  $bot_token = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN';
  $channel_username = '@YOUR_CHANNEL_USERNAME';
  $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$bot_token.'/sendMessage';
  $data = array('chat_id' => $channel_username, 'text' => $message);
  $options = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST','content' => json_encode($data),'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
              "Accept: application/json\r\n"));
  $context  = stream_context_create($options);
  $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  return $result;
}

function send_post_to_telegram_channel($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
  if ($new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' && $new_status != 'draft') {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $key = 'telegram_sent_' . $post_id;
    $sent = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
    if ($sent || wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
      return;
    }
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink($post_id);
    $message = " " . $title . " " . $permalink;
    send_telegram_message($message);
    update_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
  }
}

function send_updated_post_to_telegram_channel($post_id) {
  if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
    return;
  }
  $key = 'telegram_sent_' . $post_id;
  $sent = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
  if ($sent) {
    return;
  }
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  $title = $post->post_title;
  $permalink = get_permalink($post_id);
  $message = " " . $title . " " . $permalink;
  send_telegram_message($message);
  update_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
```